# Sweave syntax highlighting in output

Tags: r, syntax-highlighting, sweave

Has anyone managed to get color syntax-highlighting working in the **output** of Sweave documents?  I've been able to customize the output style by adding boxes, etc. in the `Sweave.sty` file as follows:

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Sinput}{Verbatim}{fontseries=bc,frame=single}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Soutput}{Verbatim}{frame=leftline}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Scode}{Verbatim}{fontseries=bc}
```

And I can get the `minted` package to do syntax highlighting of verbatim-code blocks in my document like so:

```
\begin{minted}{perl}
use Foo::Bar;
...
\end{minted}
```

but I'm not sure how to combine the two for R input sections.  I tried the following:

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Sinput}{minted}{r}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Scode}{minted}{r}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5113/how-to-colorize-syntax-using-r-sweave) on tex.StackExchange might be interesting for you, as it suggest loading the [SweaveListingUtils package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SweaveListingUtils/index.html) in R for easy solution.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't seem to get `SweaveListingUtils` to work, but I'll have a try at the `\renewenvironment` stuff.

Comment: @Ken Williams: could you specify what is the problem with the package? I hoped it could work for you as a nice and easy solution. If the error would persist, good luck with other alternatives!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, look at some of the vignettes for [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) as for example (to pick just one) the [Rcpp-FAQ pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf).

We use the [highlight](http://cran.r-project.org/package=highlight) by Romain which itself can farm out to the [hightlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.html) binary by Andre Simon.  It makes everything a little more involved---Makefiles for the vignettes etc pp---but we get colourful output from R and C/C++ code.  Which makes it worth it.

Answer (score 5):

I have a solution that has worked for me, I have not tried it on any other systems though so things may not work out of the box for you. I've posted some code at https://gist.github.com/797478 that is a set of modified Rweave driver functions that make use of minted blocks instead of verbatim blocks.

To use this driver just specify it when calling the Sweave function with the driver=RweaveLatexMinted() option.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I've ended up solving it, starting from @daroczig's suggestion.

```
\usepackage{minted}

\renewenvironment{Sinput}{\minted[frame=single]{r}}{\endminted}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Soutput}{Verbatim}{frame=leftline}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Scode}{Verbatim}{}
```

While I was at it, I needed to get caching working because I'm using large data sets and one chunk was taking around 3 minutes to complete.  So I wrote this `zsh` shell function to process an `.Rnw` file with caching:

```
function sweaveCache() {
    Rscript -e "library(cacheSweave); setCacheDir(getwd()); Sweave('$1.Rnw', driver = cacheSweaveDriver)" &&
    pdflatex --shell-escape $1.tex &&
    open $1.pdf
}
```

Now I just do `sweaveCache myFile` and I get the result opened in Preview (on OS X).

Comment: BTW, the `--shell-escape` thingy is needed by `minted` because it does the syntax highlighting in Python.

Comment: In r-studio the shell escape is done by Tools - Global Options - Sweave - Enable shell escape commands.

Minted also requires the python package "pygments".
On Linux, installed by "sudo pip2 install Pygments"