# Syntax highlight in R Sweave

Tags: r, syntax-highlighting, sweave

I am fairly new to doing report with R Sweave and know the very basic applications of Latex. And I have been asked to produce some statistical reports. The R markdown is great and simple, and by default it has really nice syntax frame and grey background and syntax highlights, however, it is quite limited in terms of other type setting, not really optimal when you want to produce lengthy reports. Then I am switching to use R Sweave in R studio.

I basically want the same after-effect similar to R markdown in the Sweave. What are the easiest ways to do it? I have previously read the following post discussing:
[Sweave syntax highlighting in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808052/sweave-syntax-highlighting-in-output). And I have tried reading those package pdf, but have no clues what they are talking about, as they seem to assume readers have prior knowledges about the rendering process.

i have checked them out, but I seem to get stuck in making it to work. Can anyone tell me step by step on how to set it up (such as what to include in preamble), if possible can you kindly upload a simple Rnw file with a demonstration?

Thank!

Comment: One option is to create a report in `rmarkdown` and export it as pdf instead of html (I'm assuming you're making html files right now).

Comment: sorry, that i did not explain clearly, I am not producing HTML, i want to produce pdf, but don't want to use r - markdown with rmd file, because r-markdown is more restricted than Sweave.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `knitr` rather than `Sweave`, you'll get syntax highlighting.  It's probably possible to do it in `Sweave`, but `knitr` makes it easier.

Go to your `Tools | Global Options | Sweave` menu (or the similar one in `Project Options`) in RStudio, and choose to Weave Rnw files using `knitr`.

The two systems are very similar, but `knitr` is generally preferable these days.

Comment: yeah, I understood now. Thank you! I thought knitr was for r-markdown. Now it is all fixed. If anyone has been using Sweave instead of knitr, and wants to convert it to knitr, one may consider the code " Sweave2knitr('filename.Rnw') " command.