# Sweave syntax highlighting in output - revisit

Tags: r, syntax-highlighting, sweave

My question is the same as the one in the link [Sweave syntax highlighting in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808052/sweave-syntax-highlighting-in-output).

I have followed the suggestion by daroczig https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5113/how-to-colorize-syntax-using-r-sweave, and created the following test.Rnw file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{fancyvrb}
\RequirePackage{listings}
\SweaveOpts{keep.source=TRUE}
<<SweaveListingsPreparations, results=tex, echo=FALSE, strip.white=false>>=
require(SweaveListingUtils)
SweaveListingPreparations()
 setToBeDefinedPkgs(pkgs = c("SweaveListingUtils","distr"),
                   keywordstyles = c("\\bf\\color{blue}","\\bf\\color{red}"))
@

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\section{Example}
This is an example with three variables in R.

<<>>=
options(continue = " ")
x  <- 10
t <- 'The brown fox'
b <- TRUE
@

<<>>=
x
@

<<>>=
t
@

<<>>=
b
@
\end{document}

<<cleaup, echo=FALSE>>=
unloadNamespace("SweaveListingUtils")
@
```

However, I get the following error message:
[image]

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have `\usepackage{Sweave}` in your document, Sweave will insert it.  But the `SweaveListingsUtils` package also inserts conflicting code.

So you need to follow the advice in the `SweaveListingsUtils` documentation, and put in a comment

```
% \usepackage{Sweave}
```

near the start of your document.  This will prevent R from inserting it.

However, do note that support for `SweaveListingsUtils` is ending; you are better off using `knitr`.

Comment: Thanks it works. I would love to switch to Knitr but I don't know how to integrate it with Latex. Any suggestions/reading would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is automatic, as long as pdflatex is on your path.  It is possible to integrate with various front ends like texworks, but takes some work.

Comment: You should post a new question rather than asking something new in a comment.