# Sweave output formating (R assign symbol shows as an arrow)

Tags: r, sweave

My question is a follow up of the following post: [Sweave syntax highlighting in output - revisit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395333/sweave-syntax-highlighting-in-output-revisit)

As you can see from the attached image below, there are a couple of issues with the formatted output.
1. The R assign symbol "<-" has been converted to an arrow.
2. The left-side quotation marks are facing left instead of right.
3. Can I choose a different color for the R script instead of this light green?

Thanks
TCS

[image]

Comment: You might consider switching to knitr, which is an updated and improved Sweave-like document generation package.

Comment: Can you please point to reading(s) showing how I can use knitr instead of Sweave to integrate my R output in a Latex document? I am writing teaching notes/book so integrating with Latex is critical for me.

Comment: Basically, use knitr::knit() instead of Sweave() and leave everything else the same.